# Google Sheets Formula With Positional Tab

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have created formulas that calculate across the sheets.
Sheet 1 is called "The Person1 Sheet"
Sheet 2 could be called anything but does the calculations.

I am grabbing values from Sheet 1 to use in the Sheet 2 calculations and it does work. However, I want to create multiple copies of this and leave Sheet 2's calculations alone. I would like to point to the first sheet not by name but by position.

The reason I want to do this is it's easier for the users if they see the name of what the sheet is for as the tab name. But Sheet 2 doesn't change.

So, for example, I have this formula in Sheet 2:
=Sumifs('The Person1 Sheet'!B1:B100, 'The Person 1 Sheet'!H1:H100, B2)

But what I really want to do is something like this:
=Sumifs(Sheet1!B1:B100, Sheet1!H1:H100, B2)

This does not seem to work. In addition, the users might be adding more tabs in here and I have a note on the first sheet that it has to remain the first sheet.

What am I missing, here?

Answer (score 0):

if your intention is to have multiple sheets and each of those sheets would have a common link to your Sheet2 where calculation will take a place - then this is not possible. point of origin needs to be always specified.

however, (not rly clear from your question) if your intention is to have multiple sheets and Sheet2 will take place as a "master sheet" eg. gather data from all sheets and run a calculation - then this is possible. in this case, you have no more than 2 choices:

- hardcode all sheets into the formula

---

```
=SUMIFS({'The Person1 Sheet'!B1:B100; 'The Person2 Sheet'!B1:B100}, 
        {'The Person1 Sheet'!H1:H100; 'The Person2 Sheet'!B1:B100}, B2)
```

- use script which will automate the hardcoding part